# How to get partial access to source code in Team Foundation Version Control

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, tfvc

We have a C# solution that contains multiple projects. Our business layer structure is like this:

```
> BLL

> -----CalcEngine
> 
> -----Components
> 
> -----Shared
```

Now we want to restrict access to CalcEngine from our new developers. We try this option before:

Restrict access to ***CalcEngine*** folder in TFVC. Whenever a developer gets the latest version of the code all file in the ***CalcEngine*** folder not mapped in client local version of the code (This is as our desire). But there is an issue with ***BLL.csproj*** file. it still contains information about files resides in CalcEngine folder. It shows them with a yellow mark that means FileNotFound.

If we delete that folder, the BLL project builds successfully, but BLL.csproj checked out and if out new developer check-in BLL.csproj file, All files in CalcEngine folder removed for other developers, and if not check in BLL.csproj new files that out new developer added to project not added to TFVC and remains on his local PC.

What is the recommended solution to control access inside a project?

Comment: Are you using TFVC or Git?

Comment: @EdwardThomson TFVC